# Need help to create an array of randomly generated numbers within a range and then displaying the frequency of each number in that range

Tags: java, arrays, random, frequency

As the title implies I'm having trouble writing a code that can do as asked. What I have is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
       int[] runs = new int[24];  
       for(int i = 0; i < runs.length; i++) {
          runs[i] = (int)(Math.random()*3 + 1);
          int count = 1;
          for (int j = i+1; j<i;j++) {
              if (runs[i] == runs[j]) {
                  count++;
              }
          }
          System.out.println(runs[i] + " " + count);          
        }   
   }
```

However, whenever I run my program, it will just list the randomly generated numbers and then a 1 next to them. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Please remember **Java !== JavaScript**, so from next time please use appropriate tags.

Comment: It looks as though you are trying to find the frequency of a value before you have generated all the values.

Answer (score 0):

```
int count1 = 0;
int count2 = 0;
int count3 = 0;
int count4 = 0;    

for(int i = 0; i < runs.length; i++) {
     runs[i] = (int)(Math.random()*3 + 1);
     if (runs[i] == 1) {
         count1++;
     } else if (runs[i] == 2) {
         count2++;
     } else if (runs[i] == 3) {
         count3++;
     } else {
         count4++;
     }
}


System.out.println("1's Frequency is: " + count1);
System.out.println("2's Frequency is: " + count2);
System.out.println("3's Frequency is: " + count3);
System.out.println("4's Frequency is: " + count4);
```

The block of code I have provided above should work. One of the problems with your code is you haven't generated all the numbers in the array prior to searching through the array to look for each number's frequency. Furthermore, the block of code within the nested loop of your code would not accomplish the task of finding out each numbers frequency.

What I did here is that it goes through the loop and assigns a random number to each spaces in the array. And, each time that it assigns a random number it also go through a series of conditional statements to count or increment the frequency of each number within the range.